# Wordpress website quote advice

Tags: freelance-websites, price

I'm looking for some advice on a quote. I've previously quoted and built a wordpress website for a client, this website is now live, and now they want me to clone that website and create a new site in which they will put new content in. I get the impression that they think this will be cheaper than the last site. I feel I should quote the same amount as the previous site, although it wont take me as long because the work is already done. But effectively i feel like I should quote on the website as a product instead of hours/time it takes to build. If i did the latter (quote on hours/time) for the clone i wouldn't be able to quote as much, and it wouldnt be worth my while.

What are peoples opinion on this? Interested to know what other freelancers would do in this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customarily, when my clients return to me to merely *alter* something I've already created, they **do** get a **reduced price**. Exactly *because* I already built what they need and they merely want to alter it. This keeps **clients happy**, which is always the goal.

If they wanted to make a few edits to the *existing* site, would you charge them a fee based on an *entire new site*? Of course not. You'd charge them for the edits.

Essentially, for a cloned site, that's *all they are asking for* - edits and **not** creation. So charge them a fee based upon *editing* and not constructing.

---

I do have **"base prices"** for smaller, particular, projects and this is explained to clients -- i.e. an HTML email design has a base price. So, if they need an email, pricing *starts* at [$xxx.xx], then may increase from there based upon the complexity desired. But they will never be charged *less* than [$xxx.xx] for an HTML email. I stress ***minimum*** fee, not "standard fee".

It's essentially a "minimal cost" for the item they are requesting. I know that for every project of *this* nature I will need to do X, Y, and Z every time. So, I build the time needed to complete those tasks into a "base fee" or "minimum price".

It would **not** be out of line of you to have a base price for a Wordpress site. That base price should be factored considering the ***smallest amount of time*** it would take to throw up a Wordpress site.

"Throw up"-- not design or configure/personalize or any of that.... merely the amount of time it would to take you to create a "canned" Wordpress site and have it live and active. (or I'll use 2 hours at my hourly rate as a minimum, if the time to complete these standard tasks is negligible.)

Then you add your editing fees on top of that "base price" or "minimum fee". The result is typically far, far less than a brand new site keeping the client happy. While at the same time providing you a bit more income than just your editing fees. Having this base pricing allows you to gain some revenue from the client's additional ROI for the new item. While at the same time, NOT charging the client standard fees as if it were an entirely new project.

---

You can also use your base price as negotiating factors at times... Telling a *new client* that [project X] has a *minimum fee* of [$xxx.xx] and pricing will increase from that point, can help to dissuade looky-loos or window-shopping clients. If your *base price* is too much for them, then their project isn't worth your time.

---

This is merely how I handle similar matters. I'm not stating it's the "correct" way to do so, only that it's worked well for me. I'd *much rather* have a client return to me over and over with more work than make a few extra dollars on one project and never see the client again.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what is more important for you at the moment: to get the maximum possible money for this project or to get a long-term client. Because if you put for the second website the same amount as for the first, then what is the reason for the customer to ask you next time when he will need such work for the third site? Why won't he try another freelancer?

Quite often, freelancers make some discount when performing work for the same customer, even when new work is not based on the results of previous one, just to expand a base of loyal customers. And in your case, given the smaller amount of real work, this approach is even more logical.

But in any case, it's up to you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You acknowledge that merely cloning the Wordpress website is easilier done than making one from scratch.

Would that apply to anyone? In other words, could the client take their business elsewhere and have another freelanmcer clone the site as easily as you could - or have you gained some knowledge that the other provider would not (normally) have?

If anyone could do the job, a reduced and competitive price based on actual time spent is almost certainly required. If not, some sort of discount on the full price would be fair.

Did you see the first website as an investment from your side? If so, is the client aware of that? It seems they are not.

Basically, it's always up for negotiation. If the client wants a larger discount, ask if there's more work forthcoming.